# Extract values from string column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

I have a column in a dataframe which have a pattern as shown in the below example

```
id=1;name=x;color=blue;
```

I am trying to extract the value for name and store it in the same dataframe with column name as "name" and value is "x"

I tried the below code but it doesn't seem to work correctly

```
df['name'] = df['col'].str.extract("'name': '(.*?)'")
```

Comment: There are no quotes in the string, this will never match `name': '(.*?)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'name': '(.*?)'` regex is meant to extract a string between `'name': '` and the next `'` char. You do not have single quotes, nor `:` in your input.

You can use

```py
df['name'] = df['col'].str.extract(r"name=([^;]*)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pKdMPf/1), `name=([^;]*)` matches the `name=` as left-hand side context and extracts one or more chars other than a `;` right after that into the `name` column.